# pull_request_target Bad object found

Tags: shell, github-actions

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
...
- name: Check changes and label
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          git diff ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}
```

when this workflow is triggerd an error is thrown `fatal: bad object 57aebf0892...`
57aebf0892... is id from  ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
i want to compare the difference between the base branch and the latest commit form the head branch  the pull request is made from forked repo

I an trying to make a workflow which compares changes made in the pull request and adds label based on type of changes made